# How to delete sms in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

Is there any way to delete incoming message like Android is doing?.Please give any solution to delete incoming message on MessageListner.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry SDK API does not contain functionality to delete SMS from the device.

Comment: I agree, so is there any way to achieve this functionality? either way if you are knowing anything or you can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: [Intercept incoming SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293685/intercept-incoming-sms/3297202#3297202) ?
It explains how to receive messages and prevent them from going to inbox